# Nikon D90 stuck on long exposures for Manual, A, S and P modes

Tags: nikon

I just got a new D90 and when I'm using Manual, A,S, and P mode the shutter is super slow and the noise stops for about 10s. After that it gave me a blank image. Sometimes on the screen it shows "job nr".  Other modes are working well so I don't think the camera has a problem.  What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the pause is the long exposure noise reduction.  You are probably getting a blank image because it is over-exposing (is it white or black?).  The question is, why are your getting such long exposures.

Some things to check, during non-auto shooting, there is an exposure compensation adjustment that will alter the level of exposure, make sure that this is set to 0, if it is set to a large amount of over-exposure, it could extend the shutter speed.  I'm not sure why this would be in manual or S modes though as that should give a fixed shutter speed based on your setting.

It is also possible that there is a defect with the camera, but it would be a very odd defect.  Does the actual time displayed for the shutter when you are taking the photos display correctly? (Does it actually match the time the shutter stays open?)  If so, then you need to figure out why it is taking such long exposures, if not, then something much weirder is going on.

Comment: the picture is totally white, could u tell me the details where should I get in to check the problem u r talking about pls

Comment: @Vanessa - I don't know Nikon's all that well (I'm a long time Canon guy.) but generally there is a spinner that you can spin counter clockwise to decrease the EC.  The value for EC is generally displayed as a marker along a number line typically going from -3 to +3 and may be displayed as an arrow if you exceed those values.  Not 100% sure if your camera does it the same though, that's just a general way they tend to work.

Comment: @Vanessa - ok, more specific details for your camera.  The EC value is displayed on the upper left of the control panel, not as a number line.  You can find more details on page 90 of your manual.  When in S or M modes, it will display the shutter speed in the same place.  It will also display the EC in the viewfinder along a numberline at the bottom unless you are in manual in which case it will be the metering.  You adjust the EC with the main command dial which is at the top right of the back of the camera.

Comment: I also HIGHLY recommend taking the time to read the manual.  There is a lot of great information in there to help you better understand the camera's features and probably some tricks to make it easier to use.

Comment: thanks u so much, I will take time to read it and update result later if I can fix it :d

Answer (score 1):

> the shutter is super slow and the noise stops for about 10s. After
>   that it gave me a blank image.

It sounds like what is happening is that your camera is exposing a photo for at least 10 seconds and as there is too much light you end up with a completely white image.

The fact that this happens on all PSAM modes is concerning as it indicates that you camera is having a problem metering the scene, and hence determining that the scene is very dark and needs a long exposure.

Have you taken the cap off? (I'm joking... ;)

First of all I would try just taking the lens off and putting it back on, making sure you hear an audible click. Perhaps there is an issue with the connection.

If you have access to other lenses then you can try swapping them, perhaps the lense you are using is the issue.

Apart from that you can try setting it to "P", ISO 200 and taking a photo somewhere bright. If you still have the problem then I'd recommend taking the camera to a service centre.

> Sometimes on the screen it shows "job nr".

This is a feature called "Long Exposure Noise Reduction" which helps reduce noise in long exposures by taking a 2nd (blank) exposure the same length as your photo. This is only being activated because your camera is taking a long exposure and can be disabled in the settings.

> Other modes are working well

Which other modes do you mean? Scene?